# How to position the content of 2 divs?

Tags: html, css-position, image-resizing

This might be a rookie problem but I can't really solve it.
I have a div which has a photo and an another div which also has a photo.
I managed to resize the photo from the parent div and the photo from the child div.

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">

          <img style="width:100%" src="img/imgSera/photo1.png" />

         <div style="width:30%; height:30%; position:absolute; top: 191px; left: 305px;">
             <img style="width:30%" src="img/imgSera/photo2.png" />
         </div>
</div>
```

When I resize by dragging the browser's corner, I'd like to be on the same position as when the browser is not resized. What am I missing? Hope I made myself understood. Thanks in advance!

Comment: position fixed?

Comment: I'd like to position the photo2 somewhere on the page and that position to be kept while resizing. :)

Comment: you want your image fixed width and height? when I use your code to resize my browser, I just saw the image getting thin.

Comment: So, when I resize my browser the 2 photos are getting smaller if I compact the browser's window. For example let's say that photo1 is a square and photo2 is a circle. If I position the circle in the upper left corner of the square and resize the browser by compacting the window, I want the square and circle to get smaller but the circle to remain in the upper left corner of the square. Hope I made myself clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Position to fixed might be enough for this.

```
          <img style="width:100%" src="img/imgSera/photo1.png" />

         <div style="width:30%; height:30%; position:fixed; top: 191px; left: 305px;">
             <img style="width:30%" src="img/imgSera/photo2.png" />
         </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to remain top left, fix the position to `top:0` and `left:`0 with `position:absolute` inside the relatively positioned div.  You had some pixel based positioning on that element and it's wrapper was percent based.  So as the larger outer image is scaled with the window (as a percent), the positioning of the smaller element seems to change (due to it's pixel based position).

Also you had a 30% width on your inner container and your image.  You can control size just with the container itself.  So I've set that inner container to 30%.  It will be 30% of the width of the outer container.  The image inside it is set to 100%, so it will fill up the width of the 30% container and both images will scale with the browser window and the small image will remain in the corner.

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">

          <img style="width:100%" src="http://placehold.it/300" />

         <div style="width:30%; height:30%; position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
             <img style="width:100%" src="http://placehold.it/250/fc0000/000000" />
         </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/treetop1500/tdk8ofsr/

You can also use percents for top and left, if you don't want it right in the corner:

```html
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">

              <img style="width:100%" src="http://placehold.it/300" />

             <div style="width:20%; height:30%; position:absolute; top: 20%; left: 20%;">
                 <img style="width:100%" src="http://placehold.it/250/fc0000/000000" />
             </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/treetop1500/b34r4rde/

Comment: Yes, but why is not working  when the top and left properties for the child div are not 0?

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Can you profide a fiddle of your code?

Comment: In your original you have the positioning of the div set as pixels.  So as the outer image scales (because it's width is 100% of whatever your browser window or it's container is) that inner element's position doesn't work well, because pixels don't scale.  You have to use percents on both.  See my second snippet that I posted above or open the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/treetop1500/b34r4rde/

Comment: As I sad above,  when I resize my browser the 2 photos are getting smaller if I compact the browser's window. For example let's say that photo1 is a square and photo2 is a circle. If I position the circle in the upper left corner of the square and resize the browser by compacting the window, I want the square and circle to get smaller but the circle to remain in the upper left corner of the square. Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Does the examples I provided not do exactly what you're asking for?